# What is regular expression for "Test123"

Tags: regex

I tried - "Test\d\d\d" and it works but problem is, String in expression could contain any number of digits so it could be "Test1" or "Test12" or "Test123". Hence it could be in range [000] to [999]

Comment: So quickly, so many answers :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should help
`Test[0-9]{1,3}`

- [0-9] specifies any digits between 0 - 9
- {1,3} specifies a range of number of
  digits ranging from 1 to 3

Answer (score 4):

```
Test[0-9]{1,3}
```

should do what you need. `[0-9]` defines a range including numbers (you could use `\d` as well), and the `{1,3}` syntax defines that the preceding pattern should happen at least once, but no more than three times.

[RegExr Demo](http://regexr.com?2tt97)

Answer (score 0):

If you mean "**any** number of digits", so that Test123456 is also viable, Test[0-9]+ or Test\d+ is another option.

Comment: He defined a range of `[000] to [999]`.

Comment: Just offering some future proofing ;)

Comment: Depends on the problem. It can be future proofing, or it can break things :).